# How do I unbind Ctrl-Alt-T?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

After I've upgraded to 12.04, I cannot unbind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> from launching gnome-terminal anymore.
I've tried disabling it completely and assigning it to another shortcut in [System Settings -> Keyboard] - nothing helps, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> still launches terminal.
Any ideas how to get rid of it?

BTW, this breaks <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in gnome-terminal itself, which is supposed to open new tab, but instead fires up new window.

Also, on a side-topic. 
This "shortcut hell" has been a problem since introduction of unity. 
Shortcuts are now configured in two different places. 
Every release they add/delete/change shortcuts - so I basically have to go and figure out how to disable/remap the ones that I use in my IDE. 
Now, it seems, you can't disable them completely (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + `) and have to override with another shortcut to unbind the default one.

What I'm really trying to ask here - does anyone know if there is a launchpad bug to fix this kind of behaviour, so I can vote \ track it? Or should I just create new one and see what happens?

Comment: Minor point, but to open a new tab in gnome-terminal you need to do Ctrl-Shift-T, not Ctrl-Alt-T.

Comment: Also, I just tried and for me I can make "launch gnome-terminal" be bound to another key, and then Ctrl-Alt-T does nothing. I have also recently upgraded to 12.04 from 11.10. Finally, where is the 2nd place for configuring shortcuts - I'm only aware of the one place.

Comment: About Ctrl-Alt-T and Ctrl-Shift-T - yes, you're right, my mistake.
Second place is compiz config - there are some keybindings you can configure in "Gnome Compatibility", "General Options" and "Unity Plugin".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On current Ubuntu metacity is no longer the default window manager, so the accepted solution no longer works. Instead there's a different setting that you can change. Set the key combination to an empty array.

In a terminal:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal '[]'
```

To undo the change again

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal
```

In case this changes again, I found this by looking for all settings that mention "terminal"

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep terminal
```

I had this problem because it interferes with an Emacs keybinding to transpose sexps.

Comment: as of the date of this comment this answer works, the accepted one has been out of date for a long time.

Comment: > I had this problem because it interferes with an Emacs keybinding to transpose sexps.

 --- Same! Glad to have found this answer. This worked for me today, even as 2020 approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I found this to work for me to disable to keyboard shortcut for running a terminal:

- Press the `super key` to start a search
- Search for `Configuration Editor` and select that application
- Drill down the following: apps >> metacity >> global_keybindings
- Scroll down until you see `run_command_terminal`
- You can **remove** or type in the word `disabled` to the right of `run_command_terminal`
- Press the red 'X' at the top of the `Configuration Editor` application
- Verify the save by going into: System Settings >> Keyboard >> Shortcuts

Pictures of what it should look like in both the `Configuration Editor` and `System Settings` area. Hope this helps!

[image]

[image]

Comment: While this looks like a solution, and disabled keybinding in gnome keyboard settings, still, it looks like something else is intercepting Cttrl-Alt-T and launching Terminal for me.
I've tried searching for all values containing <Control><Alt>T in Configuration Editor and disabling them - there was a bunch related to gnome compatibility compiz plugin. Unfortunately, that didn't help. This has prob something to do with my 11.10->12.04 upgrade - I was upgrading when it was in alpha stage. Something went wrong, and I had to boot to live cd and manually recover. Any ideas what else could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Alepar: Look into "Custom Shortcuts" in Settings/Keyboard (seen in the ruffEdgz' answer). I had the same problem; I could not remove the custom shortcut, but it was possible to rebind it so that it did not interfere with the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for anyone looking for a more updated answer, or an answer for UbuntuMATE, Go to **Config Editor**, and look for the following:

**org** > **mate** > **applications** > **terminal**

And change `exec` to whatever application you like and remove `exec-arg`, this changed the bind for me because I used terminator, I'm not sure what else that changes.