# Unbind Alt-Click (gnome classic)

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

Ubuntu 12.04, Gnome classic.

Trying to unbind/change < <kbd>Alt</kbd>*click-1* > that moves windows (reason being another app is using that and anyway I want to change it).

But couldn't find it in

- [How to unbind Shift-Alt Up shortkey in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/171489/how-to-unbind-shift-alt-up-shortkey-in-12-04) (compiz)
- [How do I unbind Ctrl-Alt-T?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133718/how-do-i-unbind-ctrl-alt-t) (config mgr)

Compiz has "Move window" disabled, and I don't find anything relevant in config-manager to remove that key binding.

Any idea?